# Responsive list to rearrange when browser is shrinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I am building a simple landing page which will be full width and contain a grid of images. The containers (li) for the the images are 17%

When I collapse my browser I know I can use media queries to change the size of the li containers but how can I do this using jquery?

I have 6 that sit on a row but when I shrink the window I want 5 on a row then when I shrink the browser further I want 4 and so on

May sound a little confusing - any help would be much appreciated

Thank you in advance

```
<div class="container">
<ul> 
 <li class="landscape"><a class="button" href="popup2"><img src="/someimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
 <li class="landscape"><a class="button" href="popup2"><img src="/someimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
 <li class="landscape"><a class="button" href="popup2"><img src="/someimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
 <li class="landscape"><a class="button" href="popup2"><img src="/someimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
 <li class="landscape"><a class="button" href="popup2"><img src="/someimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
 <li class="landscape"><a class="button" href="popup2"><img src="/someimg.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.resize function for every time that the user resize the window.

jQuery ->

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
  // put your code here
});
```

javascript ->

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // put your code here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve what you want via media queries and css, is there any reason why you need to use jquery?

Modify the li width at each of your break point to fill the 100% container. eg 33% at 768px (3 images), 25% at 1024px (4 images) etc etc

If you are dropping these elements off just use nth child selector to hide them at the relative size. If they are visible the will display below at the size you have specified (I assume these elements use floats)

Answer (score 0):

give to the container `width:100%` and for li fixed width or `inline-block`
https://jsfiddle.net/vv6t9pud/